# Determine the matrix representation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Consider the linear transformation
$$
L : P_3(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow P_3(\mathbb{R})
$$
given by
$$
L(p) = p' + p(1).
$$
 I have to calculate the matrix representation $_V[L]_V$ where $V = (1,X,X^2)$ is a basis for $P_3(\mathbb{R})$. I know I have to calculate $L(1), L(X), L(X^2)$ but I am little bit unsure.
I know that $L(1) = (1)' + 1 = 1$ but is $L(X) = (X)' + 1 = 2$ or $L(X) = (X)' + X = 1 + X$. I can't remember. Do you mind clarifying?

Comment: $L(X^2)=(X^2)'+X\Big|_{x=1}=2X+1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X$ is written for the polynomial $p(X) = X$. This means $p(1) = 1$. Hence,
$$L(p(X)) = p(X)' 
+ p(1) = X' + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2.$$

Comment: Thus $_V[L]_V = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: @Mathias This is correct.

Comment: What if it was $L(p) = p' = p(2)$. Is $L(p(X^2)) = p(X^2)' + p(2) = X^2' + 2^2 = 2X+4$

Comment: Yes, this is also true. But you should be careful with your notation. $p(X) = X^2$, then you write $L(p(X)) = L(X^2)$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Jan! :)